# how to trigger this example with schedule date and time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Visit [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqZ88/32/)

//wrap that HTML inside a wrapper div i.e.

```
<div style="float:left;"><a href="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=1401348&quantity=1&product_id=8" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/m-12.gif" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-155" /></a></div>
<div style="float:right;"><a href="http://www.msl37.org/wp-content/d/5.htm" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://www.interestingquestionstoaskagirl.msl37.org/wp-content/esg7/kas-34.jpg" title="" width="148" height="25" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-160" /></a></div>
```

Comment: You want to trigger a `click`-event with javascript and add the datetime when it was "clicked"? Is that correct?

Comment: What is your question? please explain it more.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: no i have provided link now.in that link we have set 5 secs to appear image on page but how we add scheduled time and date to trigger that image so that after specific date and time we can see that image or post?????

Comment: @TobiasKun:---- you are almost correct in that i want to put a specific time and date so that my post/image/video display on specific date and time which i set.now you understand what my query?

Answer (score 0):

If you change your javascript to this, it will trigger at the specified date and time

```
// The date and time you want to trigger the function
var triggerDateTime = new Date(2014, 2, 10, 10, 15, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = "block";
},triggerDateTime - new Date());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EqZ88/34/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

    //set required date 
    var req_date = 10;
    var req_month = 4;
    var req_year = 2014;


    var dt = new Date();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var min =  dt.getMinutes();
    var sec = dt.getSeconds();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = dt.getDate();
    var year = dt.getFullYear();


    if(date ==req_date && month == req_month && year==req_year ){
      document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = "block";
    }

},5000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EqZ88/36/)

Comment: @johan:-- Thank you for the solution.Can you explain me from where the date will be set?how can i change the date?

Comment: thank you dheeraj for the solution.i will implement and see the result in my code.